# Get owin cookie name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

In MVC 5 I configured OWIN authentication in `Startup.Auth.cs` and I set my cookie name:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    ...
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ...
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ...
            CookieName = "MYCOOKIE",
    ...
```

Now I want to retrieve this cookie name in the other place in my application (in another `.cs` file). How can I access to this config?

**P.S.** I can define a `static` string and use it, but I don't want to do this way.

Comment: Cookie name is unchanged during the execution of the application. Having a public constant that defines cookie name should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class set a `const` value.

You can access `CookieProvider.OWINCOOKI` value.

```
public class CookieProvider
{
    public const string OWINCOOKIE = "MYCOOKIE";
}


public partial class Startup
{
    ...
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ...
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ...
            CookieName = CookieProvider.OWINCOOKIE,
    ...
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to use `const` or `static` to get cookie name.

You can use webcofing Setting.

Add `<add key="OwinCookie" value="OWINCOOKIE"/>` on webconfig's `appSettings`

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="OwinCookie" value="OWINCOOKIE"/>
</appSettings>
```

using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` to get cookieName

```
public partial class Startup
{
    ...
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ...
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ...
            CookieName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OwinCookie"],
    ...
```

Comment: I said that I don't want to use `static` (or `const`) members. I knew this way. I want to find a way to access owin config options like cookie name. I vote your answer because it's a true way too.

Comment: Why didn't you want to use  `static` or `const` to get cookie name?